# Golang: find string in file and show line number

Tags: string, algorithm, loops, go

```
read, err := ioutil.ReadFile(path)
if err != nil {
    return err
}

if strings.Contains(string(read), "STRING") {
    // display line number?
    // what if many occurrences of the string
    // how to display for each the line number?
}
```

I'm trying to search files for a specific string and display the line number at which the string is located.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use [scanner](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#NewScanner) to iterate over the file, line-by-line, incrementing your line count on each loop.

e.g.

```
f, err := os.Open(path)
if err != nil {
    return 0, err
}
defer f.Close()

// Splits on newlines by default.
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(f)

line := 1
// https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner.Scan
for scanner.Scan() {
    if strings.Contains(scanner.Text(), "yourstring") {
        return line, nil
    }

    line++
}

if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
    // Handle the error
}
```

Update: if you need to do this across 'thousands of files' (as per the comment on another answer), then you would wrap this approach in a [worker pool](https://gobyexample.com/worker-pools) and run this concurrently.

Comment: It is probably better to use `scanner.Bytes()` and `bytes.Contains` to avoid conversions from `[]byte` to `string`. I'm not sure a worker pool will help in the thousands of files case -- the code will be (or should be) io-bound, and multiple goroutines will mean more disk seeking.

Comment: A worker pool would depend on whether you read the files into memory first, how big they are, how many concurrently, etc. Not enough information to go by, but a small worker pool is unlikely to have downsides on even a single SSD.

Comment: If you want to read constant data, then try this ``bufio.NewScanner(strings.NewReader(`bar foo ...`))``   [strings.NewReader](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#NewReader)

Answer (score 3):

Hi Try this out.

```
    /* ioutil.ReadFile returns []byte, error */
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile("output.txt")
    /* ... omitted error check..and please add ... */
    /* find index of newline */
    file := string(data)
    line := 0
    /* func Split(s, sep string) []string */
    temp := strings.Split(file, "\n")

    for _, item := range temp {
        fmt.Println("[",line,"]\t",item)
        line++
    }
```

Basically, it will read file using ioutil package and find out newline from the contents. Strings packages is very useful when you find a certain character or newlines and so on.  Take a look at GO's official webpage for further note and examples. (https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Split).

I made a "output.txt" from (https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Split) above and expected output should be

```
[ 0 ]    
[ 1 ]    Examples
[ 2 ]    
[ 3 ]        Contains
[ 4 ]        ContainsAny
[ 5 ]        Count
[ 6 ]        EqualFold
[ 7 ]        Fields
[ 8 ]        FieldsFunc
[ 9 ]        HasPrefix
[ 10 ]       HasSuffix
...
```

Regarding the format, you can modify 
    `fmt.Println("[",line,"]\t",item)` with fmt.Printf(

Answer (score 1):

Split the file in lines first (can be done using `strings.Split` or `bytes.Split`), then iterate through the lines and check each line individually if it contains the wanted string. If yes, then print the line number.

Comment: Won't this be impractical for searching through thousands of files? Or are you sure it's best solution?

Comment: Another approach is to split the file according to the string you search, and count the number of line breaks in the segments, so you can compute the line numbers. Honestly, I do not know which is the most efficient, it depends on how go handles those operations internally.